# Tidy: avoid moving script tags

Tags: javascript, html, tidy, htmltidy

I am using this kind of code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <script>
        document.write("<td>foo</td");
    </script>
    </tr>
</table>
```

After using HTML tidy, the script tag is removed outside of the table, hence ruins the page layout. I know, this code is not state of the art. Yet, is there anything I can do to tidy it without manually rewiring my pages?

Thanks

Comment: That's not "not state of the art", it's just plain wrong. Only `td` and `th` tags are allowed inside `tr` elements, so there's no way to make HTML Tidy think that's all right.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to either write the whole table dynamically:

```
<script>
    document.write("<table>");
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td>foo</td>");
    document.write("</tr>");
    document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Or use more proper code like:

```
<table>
    <tr id="Row1"></tr>
</table>
<script>
    document.getElementById("Row1").innerHTML = "<td>foo</td>";
</script>
```